# $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt$ is divergent?

Tags: calculus, integration

> How to show that $\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt$ is divergent?

I know how to show that $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt$ is divergent

So maybe
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt
 = \int_1^e \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt + \int_e^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt
 \geq \int_1^e \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt + \int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt = \infty
$$

so it diverges by comparison test? is this right? THANKS!

Comment: Looks good to me! You might want to argue that the integral from $1$ to $e$ is finite, but that's easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your solution is good, but perhaps this is simpler:

If $u = \ln t$ the $du = dt/t$ so
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln t}{t} dt = \int_0^\infty udu = \left. \frac{u^2}{2} \right|_0^\infty
$$

Answer (score 3):

Your way by direct comparison is fine and we can simplify it further as follows

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt
 \ge \int_e^\infty \frac{\ln(t)}{t}dt
 \geq  \int_e^\infty \frac{1}{t}dt = \infty$$